# Remote deployment with pyCharm + Django + Raspberry pi

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi, pycharm, remote-access

I'm developing web application on raspberry pi using Django. I set up django, virtual enviroment and server on raspberry pi. Now I want to write code in pyCharm and deploy it on remote machine(raspi). I've copied all folders (virtualenviroment also) to my pc. I'm wondering- how can I 'take' this virtual enviroment from raspberry to have also working on pyCharm? I've tired:

```
C:\MyPath\AquaControl>activate AquaControlEnv
Could not find conda environment: AquaControlEnv
```

and by using

```
conda info --envs


C:\MyPath\AquaControl>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3
```

Only this one from PC is discoverable. Or I can create local virtual enviroment and this will not cause any problems with deployment on remote?

Comment: You don't copy virtual environments 
(especially not between different architectures). Recreate them using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: check remote interpreter in pycharm. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone will face similar problem: After executing command from Klaus.D I had another problem => packages didn't want to install. My default python version on raspberry was 2.7 but in virtual enviroment I had python 3.5 and on pyCharm I was working with Django 2.1 which needed python 3.5. I changed default version and then packages installed successfully. My workflow is: do a code on pyCharm, upload on raspi and with putty and virtualenv I run server.